# Difference and use cases with useEffect and useMemo hooks on React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

This is a performance question since both ways are working.

I need to update a value according to the existence of another value.
So I did the follow:

```
const value = useMemo(() => (a ? valueB : valueC), [a]);
```

This is ok and works but I read that the useMemo hook is not recommended for easy functions, so I changed to:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState()

useEffect(()=> {
   a ? setValue(valueB) : setValue(valueC)
}, [a])
```

What is the more performant way to do that and why? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The recommendations are avoid useMemo without heavy functions to process... in this case in specific, i think you dont need that... Since you can just create a new variable and attach the value to her, without effects or state.

`const value = a ? valueB : valueC;`

But if this will be a initial value for something greater, with state manipulations which causes rerender, you can just initialize your state with this incoming prop

`const [value, setValue] = useState(a ? valueB : valueC);`

Answer (score 0):

Difference is that `useMemo` returns value(either cached result or calculated-just-moment-ago) and this value we use to compose result JSX.

Version with `useEffect` will call setter for `useState` which will cause another re-render with new value. 2 re-renders instead of 1.

> I read that the useMemo hook is not recommended for easy functions

suggests to use normal calculation each time:

```
const value = a ? valueB : valueC;
```

rather using `useEffect`